# Why do I get "Not Enough Image Data" from Pillow on Windows, while the same code works well on Linux?

Tags: python, windows, newline, python-imaging-library

We are trying to port the support file of a homework assignment that runs well on Linux to Windows. A part of the assignment require students to manipulate raw image data, and the support files use Python to convert between raw data and image files. The code for converting image files to raw data is:

```
import os, sys
from PIL import Image
from struct import *

fileName = sys.argv[1]
try:
    myImg = Image.open(fileName)
    width,height = myImg.size
    sys.stdout.write(pack("ii",width,height))
    rgbImg = myImg.convert("RGB")
    pixels = rgbImg.getdata()
    for (r,g,b) in pixels:
        sys.stdout.write(pack("BBB", r,g,b)) 
except IOError, e:
    print >> sys.stderr, "%s: %s\n\nCannot open or understand %s" % (sys.argv[0], str(e), fileName)
```

While the code for converting back is:

```
import os, sys
from PIL import Image
from struct import *

fileName = sys.argv[1]
try:
    dimensions = sys.stdin.read(2*4)
    width,height = unpack("ii", dimensions)

    pixels = sys.stdin.read(3*width*height)
    myImg = Image.frombytes("RGB", (width, height), pixels, "raw", "RGB", 0, 1)
    myImg.save(fileName, "PNG")
except IOError, e:
    print >> sys.stderr, "%s: %s\n\nCannot open or write to %s" % (sys.argv[0], str(e), fileName)
```

The standard outputs and inputs are redirected to files in the code of the testing facilities. The code works fine on Linux, but doesn't work well on Windows. We always get the following error when trying to write image files on Windows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image-rewrite.py", line 16, in <module>
    myImg = Image.frombytes("RGB", (width, height), pixels, "raw", "RGB", 0, 1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2100, in frombytes
    im.frombytes(data, decoder_name, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 742, in frombytes
    raise ValueError("not enough image data")
ValueError: not enough image data
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong going on? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `stdin` / `stdout` to transmit binary data on Windows is a bad idea. Windows uses CRLF (`'\r\n'` ) as the End Of Line marker, and that gets translated to `\n` on input and translated back on output; that translation process can play havoc with binary data.

Instead, you should use named files, and open them in binary mode.

---

BTW, in Python 3 you cannot read / write binary data directly from / to `sys.stdin` / `sys.stdout`, even on Linux. Instead, you need to use the `read` / `write` methods  of `sys.stdin.buffer` / `sys.stdout.buffer`.

Comment: For Python 2, the `-u` option uses unbuffered standard I/O. On Windows it also switches to binary mode, i.e. it disables newline translation on `stdin` and `stdout`. You can also set the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`, but setting this permanently breaks Python 2's interactive REPL, which depends on newline translation when reading from the Windows console.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for that info! I have sometimes used the `-u` option (in Python 2), but forgot that it also set `stdout` / `stderr` to binary, (being on Linux, text vs binary mode is rarely something I think about, but I still do try to open my files in the appropriate mode), but I was totally unaware that it had any effect on `stdin`.

Comment: The command-line help doesn't mention `stdin`, but it is [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u).